# i'm getting unexpected number error while retrieving data fromrest api

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var app=angular.module('ssbank',['ngResource']);
```

the below code is to enable cross origin requests

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
   $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}
]);

app.controller('bankcontroller',function($scope,$http,$resource){
    var user=$resource("http://localhost:9080/RestService/hello");
    $scope.data=user.get();
});
```

[i'm able retrieve the data from rest service successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIL3J.png)
  `

Comment: Try using `user.query()` instead of `user.get()` since it is set to handle array by default

Comment: hi, thanks for responding, still it is giving me the same error message.

Comment: Have you tried using `$http`? Also is endpoint CORS enabled?

Comment: yes i used `$http` also , i created a new filter class , to enable CORS

Comment: i found the error,the problem is with the JSON